# Knockout: limit number of selection in multiple-select

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I'm following the [official tutorial](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) on how to make a multiple-select binding.

I need to limit the number of selection: for example, in a multi-select with 6 options only 2 can be selected. Is it possible?

In case, which alternatives I need to do for achieving such result (ex. query, select2, ...)?

Comment: you can also try like this http://jsfiddle.net/nZtZd/91/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to limit the number of selection: for example, in a multi-select with 6 options only 2 can be selected. Is it possible?

Yes, this is easy.

Create an observable array that contains the selected objects. Write logic in your viewmodel that either

- disables the UI for selecting more objects when that array hits your limit (by creating a `ko.computed` – like `canAddMoreItems` – that returns true or false based on the array length and then for example binding `enabled` to it accordingly) — that's the easy alternative — or
- removes the oldest selected item when the user selects one over the limit

The following implements the second variant, as it's a bit more difficult than the first.

```js
function MultiSelect(items, limit) {
    var self = this,
        selection = [];
  
    self.items = items;
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
    
    self.selectedItems.subscribe(function (selectedItems) {
        // find out which new items the user selected, add them to our list
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(selectedItems, function (item) {
            if (ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(selection, item) === -1) {
                selection.push(item);
            }
        });

        // find out which items the user de-selected, remove them from our list
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(selection, function (item) {
            if (ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(selectedItems, item) === -1) {
                ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(selection, item);
            }
        });

        // remove excess items directly from the underlying selectedItems array
        if (selectedItems.length > limit) {
            self.selectedItems.valueWillMutate();
            while (selectedItems.length > limit) {
                ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(selectedItems, selection.shift());
            }
            self.selectedItems.valueHasMutated();
        }
    });
}

var vm = new MultiSelect(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'], 2);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select multiple size="6" data-bind="
  options: items,
  selectedOptions: selectedItems
"></select>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Notes:

The `selection` helper variable maintains the order in which the user clicked the items. This is necessary because the `selectedOptions` binding keeps the selected items in the same order as they are in the source array (`options` binding).

Unfortunately that makes it impossible to determine what is the oldest option (i.e. the first one to throw out when the user selects over the limit). In the interest of a smooth user experience it's nice to keep track of what the user did.

Since the user can select in other ways than clicking with the mouse (dragging the mouse or holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while using the cursor keys also work), the code must be able to deal with the situation where the "change delta" is more than one item.

The little song and dance routine with `valueWillMutate` and `valueHasMutated` is explained over here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html